# Have userID in view, need userName posted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view

In my Get/Index view I am posting to my Post/Index method in the holidayController.
So i am posting over the UserID, how can I use this to access the userName?

Iv tried

```
 public ViewResult Index(int userID, string userName)
        {
            Person person = new Person();
            //this assigns person.Id to the user Id
            person.Id = userID;
            //i want to assign name of person to the string userName
             userName = person.name;
}
```

This is flashing up cant be null for person.name?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I think you are in the wrong direction here...

Comment: Are you using the default built in aspnetdb?

Comment: @Pabloker, thanks for the reply you are correct i was in the wrong direction, i got it in the end using linq: Person person = (from p in db.People
                             where p.Id == HolidayDate
                             select p).FirstOrDefault();

            userName = person.Name;

Comment: @garfbradaz thanks for the reply, got it sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to initialize the name of the person like this.

```
person.Name = userName
```

however I think that you are having the Name cannot be null exception, because you have a **Require**  attribute on the Name property in your Person class

and probably the userName that gets passed to the action is NULL

after reading the question again **UPDATE:**

You can simply save the users name to TempData or the Session an than access in the action that you need this data.

```
TempData["userName"] = person.Name;
```

Or

```
Session["userName"] = person.Name;
```

Or you can save it to the ViewBag or ViewData if you need that data for your view.

```
ViewBag.UserName = person.Name
```

Or

```
ViewData["userName"] = person.Name
```

Comment: Please, read the question again..he wants to `assign name of person to the string userName`

Comment: Thanks for the reply ended up usng LINQ to sort it

Answer (score 0):

Is `string userName` filled in? If so, you can use `person.Name = userName` if it has a public setter. If the string is not filled in, how are you storing those objects? If you use a database, you could lookup the Person object in the database using the ID you provided.

Comment: Please, read the question again..he wants to `assign name of person to the string userName`

Comment: thanks for the reply, was going about it the wrong way, ended up using LINQ

Answer (score -1):

You might use the `ref` keyword before `string userName` in the function definition:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/14akc2c7(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply but got it sorted